# I'm living in the Northwest US; can I apply for a Schengen visa in Vancouver, BC?

Tags: canada, schengen-visas, us-residents, seattle

I'm living in Seattle. Can I obtain a Schengen visa in Vancouver, BC, specifically at the Italian Consulate?

Answer (score 2):

Embassies and consulates almost always prefer you use the embassy or consulate of the country you’re a resident of. Even if there isn’t a legal restriction, they’re more familiar with the documentation you might provide.

Given that there is an [honorary Italian consulate](https://conssanfrancisco.esteri.it/consolato_sanfrancisco/en/il_consolato/la_rete_consolare/la-rete-consolare.html) located in Seattle: https://www.embassypages.com/missions/embassy7356/

You may want to email both the San Francisco and Seattle consulates and ask for their advice because as @Giorgio notes, not all honorary consulates can handle all services.

Comment: You might want to use the [official site](https://conssanfrancisco.esteri.it/consolato_sanfrancisco/en/il_consolato/la_rete_consolare/la-rete-consolare.html) as the link (I've found that embassypages can be out of date). Also, as it's an Honorary Consul, it may not issue visas, as not all do.